# Superscript size when using reflected glyphs

Tags: superscripts, reflection

I want to use a reflected `$\Gamma$` symbol as a superscript in math mode.
I am using `\reflectbox` from `graphicx` package to declare a macro for reflected symbol and it works in normal size (math) mode.

However, when I try to use the macro as a superscript, the reflected symbol does not scale appropriately. What can be done?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\GammaInv}  {        } { \reflectbox{$\Gamma$} }

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    % regular letter superscript
    L^{\Gamma} \\
    % reflected letter superscript (does not scale down as expected)
    L^{\GammaInv} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `\mathpalette`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GammaInv}{}{\mathpalette\doGammaInv\relax}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\doGammaInv}{mm}{%
  \reflectbox{$\m@th#1\Gamma$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    % regular letter superscript
    L^{\Gamma} \\
    % reflected letter superscript (does not scale down as expected)
    L^{\GammaInv}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\mathpalette` macro wants two arguments: the first is an auxiliary macro which will receive as first argument a math style selection. The second one can be used for variable input, an example follows.

[image]